# Reverse for 'products-by-sub-category' with arguments '('fantasy-fiction',)' not found

Tags: python, django

When I am using the get_url function in the SubCategroy model it gives an error like this.

*NoReverseMatch at /products/category/fiction/
Reverse for 'products-by-sub-category' with arguments '('fantasy-fiction',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['products/\^category/\(\?P(?P<category_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\[\-\\W\]\+\)/\(\?P(?P<sub_category_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\[\-\\w\]\+\)/\$\Z']*

there are no errors when I am not using {{sub_category.get_url }} in my HTML. but I want to use the URLs of each sub-category in the HTML. what did I do wrong?

the way I used sub-categories maybe not be a good idea. if there are any good suggestions please add to your answer.

also, I want to use language as also another categorizing criterion. is there a better or alternate way to implement this?

**My html**

```
{% if category_links %}
{% for category in category_links %}
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link  dropdown-toggle active" href="" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">{{ category.category_name }}</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu list-unstyled category-list ">
        {% if sub_category_links %}
          {% for sub_category in sub_category_links %}
            {% if sub_category.category_id == category.pk %}
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ sub_category.get_url }}"> {{ sub_category.subcategory_name }} </a></li>
            {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ category.get_url }}"> View All </a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.products, name="products"),
    path('category/<slug:category_slug>/', views.products, name='products-by-category'),
    path('category/<slug:category_slug>/<slug:sub_category_slug>/', views.products, name='products-by-sub-category'),
    path('language/<slug:language_slug>/', views.products_by_language, name='products-by-language'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
def products(request, category_slug=None, sub_category_slug= None):
  categories = None
  sub_categories = None
  products = None

  if category_slug is not None:
    if sub_category_slug is not None:
      sub_categories = get_object_or_404(SubCategory, slug=sub_category_slug)
      products = Products.objects.filter(sub_category=sub_categories, is_available=True)

    else:
      categories = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
      sub_categories = SubCategory.objects.filter(category=categories)
      products = Products.objects.filter(sub_category__in=sub_categories, is_available=True)



  else:
    products = Products.objects.all().filter(is_available=True)


  context = {
    'products' : products
  }
  return render(request, 'products/products.html', context)


def products_by_language(request, language_slug=None):
  language = None
  products = None

  if language_slug is not None:
      language = get_object_or_404(Language, slug=language_slug)
      products = Products.objects.filter(language=language, is_available=True)

  else:
    products = Products.objects.all().filter(is_available=True)

  context = {
    'products' : products
  }
  return render(request, 'products/products.html', context)
```

**models.py**

```
class Category(models.Model):
  category_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
  slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
  description = models.TextField(max_length=255, blank=True)
  image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/categories', blank=True)

  class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'category'
    verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

  def get_url(self):
    return reverse('products-by-category', args=[self.slug])

  def __str__(self):
    return self.category_name


class SubCategory(models.Model):
  subcategory_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
  slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
  category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
  description = models.TextField(max_length=255, blank=True)
  image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/subcategories', blank=True)

  class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'sub category'
    verbose_name_plural = 'sub categories'

  def get_url(self):
    return reverse('products-by-sub-category', args=[self.slug])

  def __str__(self):
    return self.subcategory_name

class Language(models.Model):
  language_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
  slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
  description = models.TextField(max_length=255, blank=True)
  image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/subcategories', blank=True)

  class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'language'
    verbose_name_plural = 'languages'

  def get_url(self):
    return reverse('products-by-language', args=[self.slug])

  def __str__(self):
    return self.language_name
```

**context_processors.py**

```
from .models import Category, SubCategory, Language

def category_links(request):
  links = Category.objects.all()
  return dict(category_links=links)

def sub_category_links(request):
  links = SubCategory.objects.all()
  return dict(sub_category_links= links)

def language_links(request):
  links = Language.objects.all()
  return dict(language_links= links)
```

**full error**

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/category/fiction/

Django Version: 4.1
Python Version: 3.10.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'accounts',
 'administrator',
 'categories',
 'products']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template /Users/Jauhar/Web development/django/ecom project/templates/include/navbar.html, error at line 82
   Reverse for 'products-by-sub-category' with arguments '('fantasy-fiction',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['products/\\^category/\\(\\?P(?P<category_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\\[\\-\\\\W\\]\\+\\)/\\(\\?P(?P<sub_category_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\\[\\-\\\\w\\]\\+\\)/\\$\\Z']
   72 :             <a class="nav-link active" href="{% url 'products' %}">Best Sellers</a>
   73 :           </li>
   74 :           {% if category_links %}
   75 :           {% for category in category_links %}
   76 :               <li class="nav-item dropdown">
   77 :                 <a class="nav-link  dropdown-toggle active" href="" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">{{ category.category_name }}</a>
   78 :                 <ul class="dropdown-menu list-unstyled category-list ">
   79 :                   {% if sub_category_links %}
   80 :                     {% for sub_category in sub_category_links %}
   81 :                       {% if sub_category.category_id == category.pk %}
   82 :                           <li><a class="dropdown-item" href=" {{ sub_category.get_url }} "> {{ sub_category.subcategory_name }} </a></li>
   83 :                       {% endif %}
   84 :                     {% endfor %}
   85 :                   {% endif %}
   86 :                     <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ category.get_url }}"> View All </a></li>
   87 :                   </ul>
   88 :               </li>
   89 :           {% endfor %}
   90 :           {% endif %}
   91 :           
   92 :           <li class="nav-item dropdown">


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Jauhar/Web development/django/ecom project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/Jauhar/Web development/django/ecom project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/Jauhar/Web development/django/ecom project/products/views.py", line 34, in products
    return render(request, 'products/products.html', context)
  File "/Users/Jauhar/Web development/django/ecom project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 24, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "/Users/Jauhar/Web development/django/ecom project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "/Users/Jauhar/Web development/django/ecom project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 62, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/Users/Jauhar/Web development/django/ecom project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 175, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/Users/Jauhar/Web development/django/ecom project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 167, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/Jauhar/Web development/django/ecom project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1005, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/Users/Jauhar/Web development/django/ecom project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1005, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/Users/Jauhar/Web development/django/ecom project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 966, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/Jauhar/Web development/django/ecom project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 157, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/Users/Jauhar/Web development/django/ecom project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 167, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/Jauhar/Web development/django/ecom project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1005, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/Users/Jauhar/Web development/django/ecom project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1005, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/Users/Jauhar/Web development/django/ecom project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 966, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/Jauhar/Web development/django/ecom project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 208, in render
    return template.render(context)
  File "/Users/Jauhar/Web development/django/ecom project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 177, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/Users/Jauhar/Web development/django/ecom project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 167, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/Jauhar/Web development/django/ecom project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1005, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/Users/Jauhar/Web development/django/ecom project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1005, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/Users/Jauhar/Web development/django/ecom project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 966, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/Jauhar/Web development/django/ecom project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 322, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/Jauhar/Web development/django/ecom project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1005, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/Users/Jauhar/Web development/django/ecom project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1005, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/Users/Jauhar/Web development/django/ecom project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 966, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/Jauhar/Web development/django/ecom project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 238, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "/Users/Jauhar/Web development/django/ecom project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 966, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/Jauhar/Web development/django/ecom project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 322, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/Jauhar/Web development/django/ecom project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1005, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/Users/Jauhar/Web development/django/ecom project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1005, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/Users/Jauhar/Web development/django/ecom project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 966, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/Jauhar/Web development/django/ecom project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 238, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "/Users/Jauhar/Web development/django/ecom project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 966, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/Jauhar/Web development/django/ecom project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 322, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/Jauhar/Web development/django/ecom project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1005, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/Users/Jauhar/Web development/django/ecom project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1005, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/Users/Jauhar/Web development/django/ecom project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 966, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/Jauhar/Web development/django/ecom project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1064, in render
    output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
  File "/Users/Jauhar/Web development/django/ecom project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 715, in resolve
    obj = self.var.resolve(context)
  File "/Users/Jauhar/Web development/django/ecom project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 847, in resolve
    value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
  File "/Users/Jauhar/Web development/django/ecom project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 914, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current()
  File "/Users/Jauhar/Web development/django/ecom project/categories/models.py", line 34, in get_url
    return reverse('products-by-sub-category', args=[self.slug])
  File "/Users/Jauhar/Web development/django/ecom project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 88, in reverse
    return resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Jauhar/Web development/django/ecom project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 803, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /products/category/fiction/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'products-by-sub-category' with arguments '('fantasy-fiction',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['products/\\^category/\\(\\?P(?P<category_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\\[\\-\\\\W\\]\\+\\)/\\(\\?P(?P<sub_category_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\\[\\-\\\\w\\]\\+\\)/\\$\\Z']
```

Comment: The products-by-sub-category route pattern in your route module has two arguments. However in `SubCategory.get_url`, you only pass a single argument to the reverse function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `products-by-sub-category` url is waiting for two slug arguments, `category_slug` and `sub_category_slug`, but you are passing just one to `reverse()`.

You can try this:

```py
class SubCategory(models.Model):
  . . .
  def get_url(self):
    return reverse(
        'products-by-sub-category',
        args=[self.category.slug, self.slug]
    )
```

Comment: it worked! Thanks. I think the way I used sub-categories and language maybe not be a good idea. if there are any alternate best practices for this?